# Moving expense transactions to different account

Tags: gnucash

If I've already added an expense to 'Misellaneous' account but I later realise I should have added it to 'Office Supplies', how can I move it?

I tried changing the `Transfer > Expenses:Office Supplies` but that didn't move it other than add it as a credit to the 'Office Supplies'.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to click on that transaction. Next, on the column of the account, change from `Misellaneous` to `Office Supplies`.

Comment: I've tried this, it just creates a credit debit within each expense account. The action I was expecting was the item with the wrong transfer account in Misellaneous to be removed from showing in the Misellaneous account.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions should be editable unless your GnuCash file has "Book Options" set which make transactions **read-only** after a certain number of days.

To check this, open up *File/Properties*.  Then on the *Accounts* tab, look at the setting for "*Day threshold for Read-Only Transactions (red line)*".  Once this value is set to "0", you should be able to edit your existing transaction split to show the intended expense account.

---

Alternatively, you could record a new adjustment transaction that debits the 'Office Supplies' account and credits the balance in 'Miscellaneous'.  This provides a fuller audit trail and may be preferable if you've already provided an expenses report to management (or club committee, etc) showing the expense recorded as 'miscellaneous'.